# Trouble with laser sensor

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, pins, pwm, digitalwrite

I have trouble with my laser sensor it doesn't work properly. When I connect all pins its doesn't work, when I remove GND and connect just the signal pin and VCC it works but the laser light is dim(I saw the light when I look at the sensor carefully ). Can someone help me?

Comment: maybe someone that can read your mind to see what you are working with

Comment: Don't disconnect GND, when the other pins are still connected. That can result in parasitic currents running through the signal pin, which can damage the electronics of the sensor.

Comment: Please show all your connections in the circuit in your question (Schematic, Wiring diagram or high-resolution in-focus picture of the actual circuit) (your ACTUAL circuit, not the circuit from a tutorial, that you might have followed). Please also include your code in the question (and please format it correctly as code). Also please include a detailed description, what is not working. What did you expect to happen and what actually happened? ("doesn't work properly" is a rather useless as a problem description). You can include all this information in your question by editing it.

Comment: What is the module you used to detect laser light is it something like this https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1gdUzxh9YBuNjy0Ffq6xIsVXaI.jpg, I think it is this module did you put the white sensor thingy to the female socket properly. (you can put it mistakenly in wrong way too)